# Stopping Timer when phone sleeps

Tags: android, timer, sleep

I'm starting a Timer on the first screen of my app. The problem comes from when the phone goes to sleep. The action that the Timer triggers cannot access the network and make the app crash. 
The solution for me would be to stop/restart the timer when the phone goes to sleep.

So are there any methods I can implement like onLowMemory() or onTerminate() from the Application class. onSleep() and onWake() would be good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Activity` code for your first screen you can override `onStop` or `onPause` and cancel your timer there. Choose whichever one works best for your purposes.

You can then re-start your timer when `onResume` or `onStart` is called.

Comment: Will this work even if I'm on a different Activity ? or do I have to override every Activity's onResume/start.

Comment: you could make a static timer that you can access through the `Application` context. If you only have the timer on the first screen then I'd guess that's the only place you need to do this.

Comment: Ok, i'll go the static route. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: I have a problem still, I can't stop the timer --'
It's static and I'm accessing it in a static way, but when I do .cancel() and .purge() the Log.w() inside the timer still shows on logcat.
Whats wrong ?

Comment: if you post a snippet of code I will edit my answer with some suggestions

Comment: Ok, just found the problem. I was declaring: public static Timer t; 
changed it to public static final Timer t; and now it stops correctly.
If you know why please explain :)
EDIT: Having troubles restarting it though.

Comment: if you make it final then when you call `cancel()` on it that instance is permanently dead. try a getter that passes back the static `Timer` instance or creates it if null. then set it to null after you kill it